# python recursion to print a pattern of '*'s

Tags: python, recursion

I want to create a recursive function f() that takes two non negative integer arguments and outputs a pattern of asterisks. The first argument represents the indentation of the pattern, and the second argument indicates the number of asterisks in the longest line in the pattern and is always a power of 2.

Ex.

```
>>>f(0, 0)
>>>f(0, 1)
*
>>>f(0, 2)
*
**
 *
>>>f(0,4)
*
**
 *
****
 *
 **
  *
```

So far I have

```
def f(x,y):
s='*'
if y is 1:
    print(s)
elif y>1:
    print(s)
    print(s*y)
print(s)
```

I can't figure out how to implement the pattern. I also can't figure out how to get the output to indent each line where needed.

Comment: Why the irregular pattern of asterisks? Also, don't use `if y is 1`. Use `if y == 1`.

Comment: Your 'pattern' is not clear (to me).

Comment: Same here... it is pretty irregular.

Comment: I get it. Each figure is the previous figure, followed by a row of 2^n asterisks, followed by the previous figure again, but indented by a space. (where n starts from 0)

Comment: in addition to the other comments made, in order for a function to be recursive, it needs to call itself

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
def f(indent, num):
    if(num > 0):
        f(indent, num//2);               # print previous pattern
        print(" "*indent + "*"*num);     # print middle row of *'s
        f(indent + 1, num//2);           # print previous pattern indented
```

Output:

```
f(0,0)   f(0,1)   f(0,2)   f(0,4)     f(0, 8)
           *        *         *          *
                    **        **         **
                     *         *          *
                              ****       ****
                               *          *
                               **         **
                                *          *
                                         ********
                                          *
                                          **
                                           *
                                          ****
                                           *
                                           **
                                            *
```

---

### Symmetric Variation

If you were going for something more **symmetric** you could try this variation:

```
def f(indent, num):
    if(num > 0):
        f(indent, num//2);
        print(" "*indent + "*"*num);
        f(indent + num//2, num//2);        # indent by num//2 instead of 1
```

Output:

```
f(0,0)   f(0,1)   f(0,2)   f(0,4)     f(0, 8)
           *        *         *          *
                    **        **         **
                     *         *          *
                              ****       ****
                                *          *
                                **         **
                                 *          *
                                         ********
                                             *
                                             **
                                              *
                                             ****
                                               *
                                               **
                                                *
```

Comment: This code results in "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison"

Comment: @user3638865, Check this Ideone example to see that it works: https://ideone.com/ycfqCg , perhaps you forgot the `if` statment?

Comment: No, to test it, I copied and pasted it exactly as is, and it gives that error.

Comment: @user3638865 I did more than just test it, I posted a link above to an online python compiler that shows that it compiles and that shows the output.

Comment: I see that. And the fact still remains that when entered in Python, that code gives that error.

Comment: @user3638865 it's because you are using python3 not python2. I'll have to see what the difference is.

Comment: @user3638865 okay it should work now. Due to changes from Python2.x to Python 3.x I had to change the `print` statements and also do explicit `int` casting when dividing `n/2`.

Comment: I seriously appreciate the effort, but it still returns that error.

Comment: Hmm well I have it working in Python2.x (https://ideone.com/ycfqCg) and Python3.x (https://ideone.com/iPWu1u). The best I can tell you is to post another StackOverflow explaining your current problem. Also, if you don't mind post back here when you figure it out (I'm curious).

Comment: One more thing I just found that might help, for integer division in Python3 it seems people say to use `n//2` instead of casting like I did `int(n/2)`. That doesn't seem like a likely cause for what you are seeing though.